# Construction of an atlas for the moduli stack $\mathcal{Bun}_X^{n,d}$ in F. Neumann's 'Algebraic Stacks and Moduli of Vector Bundles'

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, algebraic-stacks, hilbert-schemes

I'm reading Frank Neumann's ["Algebraic Stacks and Moduli of
Vector Bundles"](https://impa.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/PM_36.pdf)  and have some problems to understand
a construction from the proof of:

> **Theorem 2.67.** (page 81) The moduli stack $\mathcal{Bun}_X^{n,d}$
> of vector bundles of rank
> n and degree $d$ on a smooth projective irreducible
> algebraic curve $X$
> of genus $g \ge 2$ is an Artin algebraic stack which is smooth and locally
> of finite type.

The proof is long therefore I will quote only the relevant parts
containing the steps in not understand. The whole proof can be looked up since the source is free available.

> *Proof.* [...] Let us now describe the construction of
> an atlas for the moduli stack $\frak{Bun}$ $_X^{n,d}$. Let
> $P_{n,d}$ be polynomial

$$P_{n,d}(x) := nx + d + n(1 - g)$$

> For every integer $m$ let $P(m) = P{n,d}(m)$ and consider
> the Quot scheme $\operatorname{Quot}
> (\mathcal{O}_X^{P(m)}, P(x+m))$
> parametrizing quotient sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules
> $\mathcal{O}_X^{P(m)}$ with prescribed Hilbert polynomial
> $P_{n,d}$. In general, a Quot scheme
> $\operatorname{Quot}(\mathcal{F}, P)$ is a fine moduli space
> for the moduli functor $\frak{Quot}$ $(Sch/S)^{op} \to (Sets)$ 
> of the moduli problem of classifying quotient sheaves of
> $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\mathcal{F}$
> with prescribed Hilbert polynomial $P$ and there exists a
> universal family of such quotient sheaves over the
> Quot-scheme $\operatorname{Quot}(\mathcal{F}, P)$.

> For every integer $m$ we define an open subscheme

$$ R_m \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Quot}
(\mathcal{O}_X^{P(m)}, P(x+m)) $$

> by requiring that

(i) the quotient sheaves $\mathcal{O}^{P(m)}_X \to 
\mathcal{F} \to 0$  parametrized by $R_m$ are
vector bundles, i.e. $\mathcal{F}$ is a locally free
$\mathcal{O}_X$-sheaf.

(ii) for every $U$-point of $R_m$ defined by the family
$ \mathcal{O}^{P(m)}_{X \times U} \to 
\mathcal{F} \to 0 $ we have that derived image
$R^1(pr_2)_* \mathcal{F} =0$ and
$(pr_2)_*:  \mathcal{O}^{P(m)}_{X \times U} \cong 
(pr_2)_* \mathcal{F}$ is an isomorphism.

> Induced by the universal family over $\operatorname{Quot}
> (\mathcal{O}_X^{P(m)}, P(x+m)) $ we get
> now a universal family $\mathcal{E}_{univ}$  of vector bundles
> over $X$ of rank $n$ and
> degree $d$ parametrized by the subscheme $R_m$.
> Therefore we get a morphism of stacks

$$r_m: R_m \to \mathcal{Bun}_X^{n,d}. $$

> From (ii) it follows (?) that if a point of $R_m$ is
> represented by a quotient sheaf of the form

$$  0\to \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{O}^{P(m)}_{X \times U}
\to \mathcal{F} \to 0 $$

> then $H^1(\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{G}^{\vee}) =0 $ (?),
> which implies that $r_m$ is a smooth morphism. [...]

**Question 1**: Why (ii) implies
$H^1(\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{G}^{\vee}) =0 $?

**Question 2**: Why
$H^1(\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{G}^{\vee}) =0 $
implies that $r_m$ is smooth? $H^1(\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{G}^{\vee})$ classifies extensions of $\mathcal{F}$ by $\mathcal{G}$. Why the conclusion that all extension are equivalent to the trivial $\mathcal{G} \oplus \mathcal{F}$ gives smoothness for $r_m$?

a note on question 1: $(pr_2)_*$ is a functor from $\mathcal{O}_{X \times U}$-
modules to $\mathcal{O}_U$-modules, so
$\mathcal{O}^{P(m)}_{X \times U}$ and
$(pr_2)_* \mathcal{F}$ live in different categories. How does
it make sense to talk about
"isomorphism" $(pr_2)_*:  
\mathcal{O}^{P(m)}_{X \times U} \cong 
(pr_2)_* \mathcal{F}$ in (ii)? Does anybody see what the author has here in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is going on exactly (misprints?), but here are some ideas:

If you take a point of $q\in R_m$ (i.e. $U=Spec(k)$) defined by a sequence

$0 \rightarrow G \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X^{P(m)}\rightarrow F \rightarrow 0$

then  by (ii) we have $H^1(F)=R^1(pr_2)_{*}F=0$.

If you apply $Hom(-,F)$ to the exact sequence gives at the end of the long exact sequence:

$Ext^1(\mathcal{O}_X^{P(m)},F)\rightarrow Ext^1(G,F)\rightarrow 0$.

But $Ext^1(\mathcal{O}_X^{P(m)},F)=H^1(F)^{P(m)}=0$ so we get $Ext^1(G,F)=H^1(F\otimes G^{\vee})=0$.

Now $Ext^1(G,F)=0$ implies that the Quot scheme ist smooth at $q$, see e.g. the book of Huybrechts-Lehn (the chapter "Grothendieck's Quot-Scheme").

Comment: Now I'm a bit confused about your argument on
$H^1(F)=R^1(pr_2)_{*}F=0$. Clearly if $U$ is a spectrum of a field
$k$, then $pr_2:= \pi: X_k \to Spec(k)$ is the canonical structure map
and the global section functor coinsides with push-forward: ie
$\Gamma((X,-) = \pi_*$, so indeed $H^i(X,F)= R^i \pi_* F$ as you wrote.
But what if $U$ is an arbitrary abstract point of $R_m$, ie a map
$f: U \to R_m$ where $U$ is an arbitrary scheme.
 Then $\Gamma(X,-) = (pr_2)_*$ is no longer true, right? 
Why we nevertheless can conclude that $H^1(F)=0$?

Comment: No in this case we have $R^1(pr_2)_{*}F=0$ which implies $H^1(F_u)=0$ for the sheaves on the fiber over a point $u\in U$. As I said, I don't really know what is meant here, only some ideas. But look at arXiv:1602.05267 on the beginning of p.17. There the authors do it exactly as I think. As one of the authors is Neumann, maybe you can just ask him, what is meant in the book?

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I think I understand your point now. Since $F$ is loc free 
(so flat)
the canonical $R^1(pr_2)_*F \otimes k(u) \to H^1(F_u)$ is surjection and
to show that $r_m$ is smooth with respect arbitrary point $U \to R_m$ we 
check it fiberwise for every $u \in U$ simply by definition of 
smoothness, that's it, right?